# jQueryMobile: Changing the font of the list-divider?

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make the font of all `list-divider`s bigger. I have tried, but failed with:

```
 .ui-li .ui-li-divider .ui-btn {
   font-size:25pt;
 }
```

Is there a way to make the font-size of a simple list-divider, big?

```
 <li data-role='list-divider'>Make Me Big</li>
```

(How would I figure that out for myself?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following custom CSS:

```
.ui-content ​.ui-listview​ .ui-li-divider{font-style: italic; font-size:3em;}​
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TdQNQ/).